# Is it possible that system remove data from ExternalCacheDir of application?

Tags: android, android-external-storage

My `Android` app uses `ExternalCacheDir` to save some files downloaded from my server which are used to show to user inside app (images, videos etc.).

In Google Play Store there's 3 comments with low grade that says after turning off application or device files are no longer available in app. All 3 users/devices with `Android 7.0`. But I've tested app in few `Android 7.0` phones and few with other versions and nothing like this happend. Also there are many high grades and other people doesn't have that problem.

Is it possible that system at some point removes them? E.g. in case of low disk (external storage) space?

I'm using ExternalCacheDir not just ExternalStorageDir to hide files a little bit from user (files are also saved with shadowed random names).

Comment: If they do cache clean, It will be removed. I don't think system will do it

Comment: @JyotiJK the comments doesn't say anything about cache cleaning so I assume they don't do that. I don't thing system do it by itself but it's weird situation

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that system at some point removes them?

Yes, where by "system" it could be the OS itself or, more likely, stuff added into the device by the manufacturer. Also, users can remove them and other apps can remove them.

> I'm using ExternalCacheDir not just ExternalStorageDir to hide files a little bit from user (files are also saved with shadowed random names).

Anything on external storage is visible to the user and to other apps.

If you specifically do not want users to have access to the files, use [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Comment: that is great answer. Is it possible to check internal storage disk space left? I need to save there some files and I don't know if it has enough disk space.

Comment: @user3626048: Note that internal storage and external storage are usually on the same partition, and so they have the same disk space (and disk space left). Given a path to a location on internal or external storage, [`StatFs`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs) can give you filesystem details, including free space.